# Столбец недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в статистической функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Запрос группирует данные с интервалом в 2 часа. Не могу понять ошибку "Столбец недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в статистической функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY". Как исправить?

```
SELECT datetimefromparts(datepart(YEAR, Datetime), 
       datepart(MONTH, Datetime), 
       datepart(DAY, Datetime), 
       datepart(HOUR, dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR, 0, Datetime)/2*2+2, 0)), 0, 0, 0) AS [DATA],
       avg(PressOilIn_P1) AS PressOilIn_P1,
       avg(PressOilOut_P1) AS PressOilOut_P1,
       avg(PressGas_P1) AS PressGas_P1,
       avg(TempOilIn_P1) AS TempOilIn_P1,
       avg(TempOilOut_P1) AS TempOilOut_P1,
       avg(TempGas_P1) AS TempGas_P1,
       avg(TempWater_P1) AS TempWater_P1,
       avg(ConsumVOil_P1) AS ConsumVOil_P1,
       avg(ConsumMOil_P1) AS ConsumMOil_P1,
       avg(ConsumGas_PP1_2hPrev) AS ConsumGas_PP1_2hPrev
FROM #temp1
GROUP BY datetimefromparts(datepart(YEAR, [Datetime]), 
         datepart(MONTH, [Datetime]), 
         datepart(DAY, [Datetime]), 
         datepart(HOUR, dateadd(HOUR, (datediff(HOUR, 0, datetime)/2*2+2),0)), 0, 0, 0)
ORDER BY [DATA] ASC
```

Comment: Если не считать отсутствия литерального совпадения выражений в SELECT и в GROUP BY, на первый взгляд нет ничего предосудительного...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
SELECT datetimefromparts(datepart(YEAR, [Datetime]), 
       datepart(MONTH, [Datetime]), 
       datepart(DAY, [Datetime]), 
       datepart(HOUR, dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR, 0, [Datetime]) / 2 * 2 + 2, 0)), 0, 0, 0) AS [DATA],
       avg(PressOilIn_P1) AS PressOilIn_P1,
       avg(PressOilOut_P1) AS PressOilOut_P1,
       avg(PressGas_P1) AS PressGas_P1,
       avg(TempOilIn_P1) AS TempOilIn_P1,
       avg(TempOilOut_P1) AS TempOilOut_P1,
       avg(TempGas_P1) AS TempGas_P1,
       avg(TempWater_P1) AS TempWater_P1,
       avg(ConsumVOil_P1) AS ConsumVOil_P1,
       avg(ConsumMOil_P1) AS ConsumMOil_P1,
       avg(ConsumGas_PP1_2hPrev) AS ConsumGas_PP1_2hPrev
FROM #temp1
GROUP BY datetimefromparts(datepart(YEAR, [Datetime]), 
         datepart(MONTH, [Datetime]), 
         datepart(DAY, [Datetime]), 
         datepart(HOUR, dateadd(HOUR, datediff(HOUR, 0, [Datetime]) / 2 * 2 + 2, 0)), 0, 0, 0)
ORDER BY [DATA]
```

Comment: В чём разница с запросом из вопроса?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов во внимательности) Фокус на последний столбец в GROUP BY и его "аналоге" в SELECT - должны быть одинаковыми